# WordPress website: favicon pixelated (plugin used)

Tags: wordpress, favicon

I am struggling with the favicon of my website built on WordPress.

I have used a 1563x1563-pixel PNG file and used *Favicon by RealFaviconGenerator* plugin to generate a proper favicon. But the favicon remains pixelated. There is anything I can do to improve the favicon quality? Thank you very much in advance (attached is the screenshot of the pixelated favicon).